# Prototype in this Array slice call, why?

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I was reading the MDN page for the JS Function's *arguments* variable:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

I understand that *arguments* is not an Array so this won't work:

```
var a = arguments.slice();
```

The solution on MDN is do do this:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

Why use `Array.prototype` and not just `Array.slice.call(arguments)`? Is using the prototype significant here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why use Array.prototype and not just Array.slice.call(arguments)?

The `Array.slice` method is part of the [**Array and String Generics**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.6#Array_and_String_generics), a set of *"static"* methods implemented as properties of the `Array` and `String` constructors.

Those methods are **non-standard**, they are available just in Mozilla-based implementations.

I've seen a lot confusion between those methods and the standard ones, but you should know that they aren't the same, if you test:

```
Array.slice === Array.prototype.slice; // false
```

You will find that they are different methods.

And by the way, if you where using that method, you don't need to use the `call` method, the first argument is the object that will be used as the `this` value (`Array.slice(arguments)`).

> Is using the prototype significant here?

Yes, the `Array` constructor is just a function, the standard `slice` method, and all the other "array methods" are defined on `Array.prototype`.

This object, `Array.prototype`, is the one in which all Array object instances inherit from.

As [@Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763555/why-use-prototype-in-this-array-slice-call/6763674#6763674) says, you could get a reference to the method using an Array instance:

```
 [].slice === Array.prototype.slice; // true
```

This, in theory, will create a new Array object, and access the `slice` method up in the prototype chain, but I remember that some implementations are starting to optimize this kind of property access, avoiding the creation of the *disposable* object, so, at some point, it will be exactly the same also talking in terms of performance.

Comment: This question is about prototypal inheritance, not about whether `Array.slice` is non-standard.

Comment: TBH, I think it was the non-standard short-hand Array.slice() call that confused me in the first place.

Comment: @Matt, extended a bit my answer.

Answer (score 3):

It should be noted that:

```
var argslice = [].slice.call(arguments);
```

works too, because if "slice" is a reference to a function on the prototype for the Array constructor then "slice" on a constructed array is (therefore) that very same function.

Answer (score 2):

`Array.slice` doesn't exist (at least not in chrome).

`slice` is part of the prototype for `Array` objects, not a method on `Array` itself, so to reference it you need to go through the prototype.

Answer (score 2):

prototype contains all functions available on "Array" objects. Array itself only refers to the constructor. Therefore you have to get the function from the prototypes and apply it to the pseudo array "arguments".

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: yes, the `prototype` is significant.

`slice` is a property of the Array object's `prototype` object. If `Array.slice` were to exist, it would be a property of the Array constructor function.

For example, when you write:

```
function MyConstructor() {
..
}

MyConstructor.someFunc = function() {
..
}
```

someFunc is a property of the MyConstructor function object so this won't work:

```
var obj = new MyConstructor();

obj.someFunc(); // Throws error
```

But this will:

```
MyConstructor.someFunc();
```

If you want to have properties available on all instances, you must add them to the `prototype` object of your constructor. For example:

```
MyConstructor.prototype.someFunc = function() {
..
};
```

Which would allow you to do this:

```
var obj = new MyConstructor();

obj.someFunc();
```