# How is 'this' context set in Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)

Tags: javascript

There are a lot of questions and answers that cover this technique, but i can't seem to find an answer to how the required `this` context gets set for call() or apply().

I understand that

`Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)`

is somewhat equivalent to

`arguments.slice()`

with `arguments` being converted into a proper array object, but if i try to use this convention with my own objects it doesn't work. I tried to write a small test doing this:

```
var Logger = function(){};
Logger.prototype.print = function(msg){ 
   console.log ((new Date()).getTime().toString() + msg); 
};

(function(){
   var o = {
    name: "Hi Bob!",
   };

   var l = new Logger();
   l.print(o.name); //works fine
   Logger.prototype.print.call(o.name); //calls print method, but 'msg' is undefined
}());
```

Is there something special in regards to the `Array.prototype` or the `arguments` object that allows that function application to work without the necessary context?

Comment: No. Only your code "is somewhat equivalent to" `o.name.print()` - which obviously does not what you want. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6763555/1048572 on how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Logger.prototype.print` print doesn't use the `this` variable anywhere, so using `call()` is pointless.  Your function expects to be passed `msg` as a parameter.  This is why `l.print(o.name);` works.

As you say in your question:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
```

is similar to `arguments.slice()`.  Therefore:

```
Logger.prototype.print.call(o.name);
```

is similar to `o.name.print()`.  Which, as you can see, makes no sense.

If you *really* wanted to use `.call()`, you could so something like:

```
Logger.prototype.print.call(null, o.name);
```

But, as you can see, this is silly, and much harder to read than just `l.print(o.name);`.

Comment: With some further tests based on your answer i now understand it. [http://jsbin.com/iwaric/1/edit](http://jsbin.com/iwaric/1/edit) . So the `arguments` parameter does in fact become the context for `slice()` which when called with no parameters returns a copy of the original array.

Comment: @mastaBlasta: Yes, that works.  As you can see, all `.call()` does is allow you to change `this` inside the function (if it's used).  In your case, I'd suggest just sticking with `l.print(o.name);`.

Comment: I don't actually have a use for this. I was just reading over some other code that used `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` and then went on a quest to find out how call() worked with what seemed like an "array" parameter. In retrospect the answer was obvious - context is just an object !!

Comment: @mastaBlasta: `Array.prototype.slice` loops through the object as if it were an array.  If the object you send to call doesn't have `.length` property (and corresponding numeric properties), `Array.prototype.slice.call` won't work.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `slice` and your function is that `slice` uses the context (`this`) while your function only use its arguments.

If you really want to use `call` with your function, use it as

```
Logger.prototype.print.call(null, o.name);
```

But you might as well use

```
 Logger.prototype.print(o.name);
```